# React Native specific locations

Tags: firebase, react-native, geolocation, google-places-api

I am building a app using React Native. There is a functionality it needs that I cant figure out with what technologies to use to tackle it. I need to let users type and find a location like Places API. Although I need to narrow the locations accessible to only beaches.

So, basically, users should be able to search up beaches and only beaches. I don't know if Places API lets people do that, and I would also want to try and find a more affordable/free service (if possible. Its not a problem if it doesn't work). Thanks for helping me understand :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that asking for recommendations on what APIs/softwares to use for your implementation is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) within Stack Overflow. Please also feel free to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help from the community. It is recommended that you try out things first after doing some researching and show us what you have tried so far by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.